# AWS Lambda - Work with services outside Amazon services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

After reading about AWS Lambda I've taken a quite interest in it. Although there is one thing that I couldn't really find any info on. So my question is, is it possible to have lambda work outside Amazon services? Say if I have a database from some other provider, would it be possible to perform operations on it through AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

AWS Lambda functions run code just like any other application. So, you can write a Lambda function that **calls any service on the Internet**, just like any computer. Of course, you'd need access to the external service across the Internet and access permissions.

There are some limitations to Lambda functions, such as functions only running for a maximum of five minutes and only 500MB of local disk space.

So when should you use Lambda? Typically, it's when you wish some code to **execute in response to some event**, such as a file being uploaded to Amazon S3, data being received via Amazon Kinesis, or a skill being activated on an Alexa device. If this fits your use-case, go for it!